# Wordpress Primary Site with IP Address instead of Domain Name

Tags: wordpress, dns, instance, amazon-lightsail

someone can help me with this.
I created a new instance using a Snapshot in Lightsail, to be able to access to the website by SSH.
The thing is that with this access, the url of the Wordpress Website and Primary Site also change to an IP Address, I want change this to my domain. Without damaging the database.
It is a multisite, I don't know if this makes a difference.

I tried with a plugin but it damaged all the database and had to redo the instance in order to go back. And I tried to connect the Instance assigning the registered domain but it didn't work.